# How to run Jenkins job via Jabber?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, xmpp, jenkins-plugins, build-automation

I configured Jabber user in Messages on my Mac. Is there any way to execute some job on Jenkins via Jabber now? Could somebody provide me clear steps for it? I'm using Jabber Plugin and Instant Messaging Plugin on Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Jabber Plugin configuration in Jenkins system configuration.
There is a setting called `Bot command prefix`.

Start your message to Jenkins with this prefix like:

`! help`

The following quotes are copied from [Jenkins Instant Messaging Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Instant+Messaging+Plugin#InstantMessagingPlugin-Managejobsviaa%27bot%27):

> [...]
>
> ### Manage jobs via a 'bot'
>
> You can control various features of jobs via a bot. To do so you can send commands to it within a chatroom (or as private messages).
>
> To execute a command send the command and its parameters send it to the bot in chatroom (or as a private message) and prefix it with the command prefix which is configured in the global configuration.
>
> For example to schedule a build for the My project job if the prefix is ! send:
>
> `!build 'My project'`
>
> Most commands can be invoked on a single job, all jobs in a view or all configured jobs. Notable commands are:
>
> - **status**: displays the status of the build i.e. last build result and last successful build
> - **health**: displays the build health as computed from the last build results, test results, (compiler warnings, findbugs warnings, ...)
> - **build**: schedules a new build of a job
> - **abort**: aborts a currently running build
> - **help**: gets a list of all available commands
>
> [...]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a bit late to the party here...
So I can definitely have Jenkins send notifications to users through Jabber, by using the post-build actions for each project (that is good).
However, for unknown reasons, the bot will reply to the first command (e.g. !help) but then will never reply again.
Nothing wrong in the logs, display the message received and that is it.

I have already spent a lot of time on this and if anyone who managed to accomplish this could help that would be awesme.

Thanks.

A.